# FATA[0000] Error: Path not specified

Tags: docker

hello everyone I have a question when I tried to copy a file from host to a docker  container, I got this error.

here is my command docker cp /usr/zhy/init.sql db001:/root

it seems dose not work. here is my docker parameters.

Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2

Answer (score 0):

it seems that my version is to low to support copy file from host to container, but I can't find any tips from their offical document.